# Angular UI Bootstrap - Docs for Bootstrap 2 gone?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I just recently noticed that the docs for http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ currently only shows the new bootstrap3 version, but for some reason I still have to use the Bootstrap 2 version.

So my question is, does anyone have a link or a cached copy from the old documentation page with bootstrap 2?

Comment: Have you heard of the [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130615000000*/http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)?